# jpegultrascan. Ошибка при работе perl-скрипта

Tags: perl

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт [jpegultrascan](https://github.com/MegaByte/jpegultrascan).

При запуске скрипта:

```
perl jpegrescan.pl 1.jpg 2.jpg
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Couldn't read file at jpegultrascan.pl line 350.
```

Запускаю скрипт с помощью [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) 5.22.1 for Windows (x86)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Приведите пример кода в пределах 350-й строки, где происходит ошибка.

Comment: Установлена ли утилита `jpegtran`? Надо установить её и указать путь к ней через опции `-p` или `-o`.